# Lost button next back in editform jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I using jqgrid vs: 4.6.0, I have set jqgrid like this, every thing ok but when i edit on popup, in the bottom of the form edit, there is no button next and back, i don't know why:

```
$("#MachineGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    pager: "MachineGrid_Nav",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: false,
    url: urlLink,
    postData: {
        gId: gId
    },
    colModel: [
        { name: "CategId", index: "CategId", label: arrMc.CategId, width: 100, editable: true},
        { name: "Category", index: "Category", label: arrMc.Category, width: 100, editable: false},
        { name: "ItemCode", index: "ItemCode", label: arrMc.ItemCode, editable: true},
        { name: "ItemName", index: "ItemName", label: arrMc.ItemName, editable: true },

        { name: "Brand", index: "Brand", label: arrMc.Brand, editable: true}
    ]

}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#MachineGrid_Nav', {
    cloneToTop: true,
    add: true,
    edit: true,
    del: true
},
{
    //edit
    recreateForm: true, closeAfterEdit: true, closeOnEscape: true, viewPagerButtons: true,
    beforeInitData: function () {

    },
    afterShowForm: function (form) {    
    }
}});
```

In image below, you can see: It lost button next and back on edit form. Have any wrong here? please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use jqGrid 4.6, but your tagged your question with free-jqgrid. What you expect when you do this, since free-jqgrid exists after jqGrid 4.6?

Comment: I think all of them fix this bug is the same => I has been chosed 2 tagged

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry that I'm not checked carefully, Now i know reason why. 
The Layout of project was not added Jquery ui css.

To fix it Just add:

```
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or add css for it like this:

```
.ui-icon-triangle-1-w, .ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url(img/jquery/ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png);
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
    background-position: -32px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-w {
    background-position: -96px -16px;
}
#pData,#nData {
    border: 1px solid #c5dbec;
    background-color: #dfeffc;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2e6e9e;
}
```

It will be Ok.